# how to navigate the lead conversion modal using navigation mixing from lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

here is my code

```
 `this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
          url:'/lightning/cmp/runtime_sales_lead__convertDesktopConsole?leadConvert__leadId=' + this.recordId+ '&ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FLead%2F'+this.recordId+'%2Fview'    
                    }
              });`
```

in the above code neither the popup for lead conversion modal is opening nor the cancel button is working

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate via standard convert button you will find out that standard convert process calls a standard component rather than a record page action.

`runtime_sales_lead__convertDesktopConsole`

Going via same concept, if you just call this from `NavigationMixin`, it works perfectly fine.

```
handleLeadConvert(){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__component',
        attributes: {
            componentName: 'runtime_sales_lead__convertDesktopConsole'
        },
        state: {
            leadConvert__leadId: '00Q7F000********' //Pass your record Id here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the code is working fine but the cancel button is not working

Comment: i try this component with lightning lead conversion url it also have same problem and  i alse try this code with classic lead conversion url its does not give me any error but i need it in lightning url